# AX2009 "DateFormat" of utcDateTime changes when printed to PDF from AX report

Tags: pdf, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have been tasked with changing the format in which the date is shown in a reporting using the a utcDateTime field.

**Example**

To change date from "5/4/2015" to "4-May-15".

I have changed the field control properties in the report setting **DateFormat**:DMY, **DateSeparator**: --, **DateYear**: TwoDigits, **DateMonth**:Short name (first three letters).

This gives me the desired result when I open the report using AX but when I printed the report to a PDF the date format has changed back to the default setting(5/4/2015). However, it doesn't occur when printed to a XPS but my company requires PDF. Also, I have tried changing the properties of the EDT and Field in the table with no luck. This only occurs with utcDateTime datatype, not date datatype.
How do I get the format I require on a PDF

Comment: Is this a MorphX report or a SSRS repert?

Comment: it is a MorphX report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output to PDF is controlled by the `PDFViewer` class and for date/time fields is done in the `writeDateTime` method. it calls the system class method `OutputDateTimeField.formatValue` to do the formatting.

You are free to roll on your own formatting in the `writeDateTime` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but can you tell me where is the 'writeDateTime' method is located. I couldn't find it.